# Is it possible to add ebs CMK encryption to elastic beanstalk created volumes?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-kms

I have some elastic beanstalk application running using terraform and I want to encrpyt its volumes with Customer managed keys from the KMS service

```
resource "aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment" "tfenvtest" {
  name                = "tf-test-name"
  application         = aws_elastic_beanstalk_application.tftest.name
  solution_stack_name = "64bit Amazon Linux 2015.03 v2.0.3 running Go 1.4"

  setting {
    namespace = "aws:ec2:vpc"
    name      = "VPCId"
    value     = "vpc-xxxxxxxx"
  }
```

I already have a module that creates the CMK key. So how can I go about doing this in terraform?

Comment: In this case, you should set the encryption at the **volume** level.

Comment: Here's the full list of options: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options-general.html I don't see an option to encrypt the EBS volume.